# Apache ServerName directive

Tags: apache

I have an apache instance config'd using SSL.  The VirtualHost uses the ServerName directive - which I have pointing to `local~host:port`.  I understand the ServerName "requires" a DNS entry.  I do not have the ServerName value as a DNS entry (it is just `local~host:port`).

The local host is called `server~1`

I also have a proxypass and proxypassreverse set to

```
`proxypass /junk/ https://local~host/junk`
`proxypassreverse /junk/ https://local~host/junk`
```

so, I enter the address of the Apache Web Server as  `https://appache_web/junk` to get to my app.
This works.  The listening port coincides with the ServerName `<Localhost:port>`.

While navigating the "junk" website,  my url changes to `https://server~1/junk/....`

So, the issue is the URL is changing, I believe the ServerName directive is internally building the FQHN for `server~l`.

SO, without creating a DNS entry - is there a way to keep my original URL as  `https://appache_web/junk`   versus having is change while navigating to `https://server~1/junk/....`

Thanks
Jim

Comment: Doesn't apache complain about the `ServerName` directive when you start it up?

Comment: Oddly - it does not complain.  Everything seems to work. It's just that the proxypass (& reverse) default to the ServerName - or building one if it doesn't match the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better asked at serverfault.com, but... you probably need to add: UseCanonicalName Off